# jars required for REST service using spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to implement a REST services using spring. I have added below JARS in the WEB-INF/lib and in Build path as well.

1. Spring core
2. Spring web
3. Spring MVC
4. Spring Context
5. Spring aop
6. Spring aspects
7. Common loggin
8. JSTL.

I have integrated the server in my Eclipse and started. When i try to hit the URL given in Spring controller, I am getting Resource not found Error. Exception I ma getting is ClassNotFound.

In the same project i have a HTML page when i try to hit it, its working fine.

Any jar i have to import or what may be the possible reason?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: are you testing on a local machine, or is this already running on a server?

Comment: I strongly suggest using maven or gradle to manage your dependencies, saves you a lot of headaches searching for the correct combination of jars. To help you solve the problem please add the stacktrace or at least the name of the class that cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the class using some utility like http://findjar.com and make sure that required dependency has been included in your project.

Do mvn dependency:tree to make sure that the respective project has been included.

If the respective project has been included, make sure that the class is there in the included version of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored SpringBoot? It is much easier to implement a REST based service. There are just 3 or 4 dependencies. You can find an example to implement a REST service here http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start